# c++ double cast void pointer

Tags: c++, casting

So I came across this piece of code reading about arduino's memory

```
void EEPROM_writeDouble(int address, double value)
{
   byte* p = (byte*)(void*)&value;
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(value); i++)
   {
      EEPROM.write(address++, *p++);
   }
}
```

What intrigues me is this line of code `byte* p = (byte*)(void*)&value;` do completety but didn't figure it out or maybe. So we have a pointer of type `byte(char)` that takes the reference of value of type `void*` and convert it to an byte pointer?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There's no strict aliasing violation here though?

Comment: @NikosC. people commonly misunderstand strict aliasing  (pointer casts have nothing to do with it)

Comment: There is no "reference" here. The expression `&value` takes the address of the variable `value`, resulting in a pointer of type `double*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a conversion from `double*` to `byte*` would not be a valid `static_cast` or `const_cast`, C++ interprets a C-style cast requesting that conversion as equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`.  (I'm assuming `byte` is a typedef for `unsigned char` or `char`.)

In the original C++98 Standard and in the C++03 Standard, there were essentially no guarantees on what a `reinterpret_cast` will do, just saying that the result was "implementation-defined".  So a single cast would probably get a pointer to the beginning of the storage for the `double` variable, but technically you couldn't count on that.

On the other hand, the two conversions in the example, from `double*` to `void*` and then from `void*` to `byte*`, are valid `static_cast` conversions, so the C-style casts would both have the behavior of a `static_cast`.  And a `static_cast` to or from a (non-null) [cv] `void*` has always guaranteed the `void*` points at the beginning of the object's storage, resulting in a pointer to an imaginary `byte` overlapping the storage of the `double` object.  (And reading from an `unsigned char` or `char` which is really in storage belonging to an object of a different type is a specific exception to the strict aliasing rules, so that's okay.)

Note that beginning with the C++11 Standard, the behavior of `reinterpret_cast`, and therefore C-style casts, was more specified for certain categories of pointer conversions: ([expr.reinterpret.cast]/7)

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.  When a prvalue `v` of type "pointer to `T1`" is converted to the type "pointer to *cv* `T2`", the result is `static_cast<`*cv*`T2*>(static_cast<`*cv*`void*>(v))` if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`, or if either type is void.  Converting a prvalue of type "pointer to `T1`" to the type "pointer to `T2`" (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value.  The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified.

So using a recent Standard mode, the two casts are no longer necessary.  (The code might have been written earlier, or might need to still work under multiple C++ versions, or might have just been written using old habits.  Though using C++-style casts to say what sort of conversion logic you really mean is nearly always a better idea than using C-style casts.)

Answer (score 3):

There's no actual reason for this cast. The code is doing type punning and the programmer who wrote the code was probably confused. When trying to get individual bytes out of a variable, you can use an `unsigned char*` pointer. Which I assume is what `byte` is in this example. You do not need to go through a `void*` pointer for this.

Answer (score 2):

The standard defines that `(byte *)p` is the same as `(byte *)(void *)p`, if `p` is a pointer.

In more detail, N4659 [expr.reinterpret.cast]/7 defines `reinterpret_cast<T1 *>(p)` as `static_cast<T1 *>(static_cast<void *>(p))`, and [expr.cast] covers that the two C-style casts resolve to `static_cast` in this case.

So this cast is redundant, we could speculate that the author didn't know the language so well.